# i want to create a customized environment to showcase products

Tags: module, products-management

Something like - http://www.pbteen.com/shop/guys-bedding/guy-bedding-tool/

Is there an extension i can use. Please Help !

Answer (score 1):

The website probably uses a canvas for product designing. There are many extensions available for it in Magento. Links of some of them are

> 1)
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/product-designer-fully-customizable.html
>
> 2)
>   http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/pdp-online-products-designer-tool.html
>
> 3) http://productsdesignercanvas.com/
>
> 4) http://www.aitoc.com/en/magentomods_custom_product_preview.html

There are many others too which you can search using Google.

**Please Note: I am in no way attached with any of the extension provider above.**